# ffmpeg : Concat multiple audio files Lost sound Issue

Tags: php, ubuntu, ffmpeg, command

I have try FFMPEG concat command, it's working and audio file concate but play only first file. I have lost second file audio sound.

```
<?php 
exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "sampleinput.mp3|sample.mp3" -acodec copy output.mp3');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use with concat protocol

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:sampleinput.mp3|sample.mp3" -acodec copy output.mp3
```

If not working, then mux to MPEG-TS first.

```
ffmpeg -i "sampleinput.mp3" -acodec copy sampleinput.ts
ffmpeg -i "sample.mp3" -acodec copy sample.ts

ffmpeg -i "concat:sampleinput.ts|sample.ts" -acodec copy output.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you write **concat:** before first filename? If it do not work try into command line not from php, and post your ffmpeg version.